# What is result of MIPS branch instruction that beyond range of PC-relative addressing?

Tags: architecture, mips

I know that how get binary code of MIPS instruction of branch (beq, ben...) to use PC-relative addressing. But I wonder how it is to work when branch offset is overflow. For example, `bne $22, $23, Label`(this instruction in 0xAFC08880, and Label in 0x3376AB00). For get offset, use PC-relative, that is 0x83B6227C. (offset = (target - (PC + 4)) / 4) However bits for offset is just 16bits, and above result is 28bits. How make binary code that instruction? Or is it impossible to translate? And is there any error or exception? I know to run this instruction, use li and jr instruction, but I want to know what is result of this instruction.

Comment: It doesn't work, as it won't encode faithfully into machine code, so in that sense it is indeed impossible. However, workarounds exist -- alternative code sequences -- and can be applied in that situation, by the compiler, assembly programmer, or the assembler.

Answer (score 0):

With 16 bits of storage for the offset (effective 18 bits after shifting left twice) your branch target range is ±128Kb.

So your assembler should issue an error when assembling your instruction as it cannot encode the offset required.

The workaround is, as you mentioned, to issue the comparison first and then if you need to do the jump then use `li` + `jr`.

If your current region and the target region where the same (not your case) then you may also use `j` instruction.